# Simple clarification about pass by reference vs. pass by value

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I declare a variable (of type TEST containing a static array) and call several functions passing a pointer to this variable.

```
typedef struct
{
     char data[50];
} TEST;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    TEST *ptr = malloc(sizeof(TEST));
    func_one(ptr);
    printf("data: %s\n", ptr->data);
}

void func_one(TEST *ptr)
{
    func_two(ptr);
}

void func_two(TEST *ptr)
{
    strcpy(ptr->data, "hello");
}
```

Will the above print statement print "hello"? My program currently prints "hello", but I am confused because from my understanding, I know that ptr is being passed by value, rather than by reference.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, the pointer is passed by value, so the pointer `ptr` in the `main` function is *copied* to the `ptr` variable in `func_one`, and it is in turn copied to the `ptr` variable in `func_two`.

You are, however, not trying to modify the pointer, but the data it points to, so it's the *data* is passed by reference, but the pointer to the data is not.

Though technically C doesn't have "pass by reference", it can only be emulated by using pointers.

Also, you would have the same outcome it you didn't allocate the data on the heap, and used the address-of operator:

```
TEST data;
func_one(&test);
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is being passed by value, that is correct. That means that the array that is being pointed to is passed by reference.

(I have a feeling that in the purest Computer Science sense that may be incorrect but it is close enough for all practical purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Pass-by-reference means you're passing a reference to some data.  Pass-by-value means you're passing a copy of some data.

In this case, you're passing a pointer by value.  But what's a pointer?  It's a reference to some data.

You're passing the pointer itself by value, but given that it's a pointer, the side effect is that any data it points to is essentially passed by reference.

Comment: But had data been a pointer (char *data), and I wanted to malloc in func_two, then func_one and func_two should receive TEST **ptr. Right?